# How to get value of Specific property of object/Array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any JQuery method avaiable to get any specific property from object ?

[image]
for example

```
var abb =dat.Abbrivation ;
```

Comment: what you mentioned in the example is the right way

Comment: it will work on chrome's console ??

Comment: i believe it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. Just grab the object.

```
var abb = dat[0].Abbrivation;
```

jQuery is unfortunately a crutch for newer programmers. It is not necessarily good practice to turn everything into a jQuery function, especially if it isn't necessary at all.

#### update

dat, being an array, needs to have its first instance selected, which then has the Abbrivation property.

Comment: It is not showing any hting when i write the same on console of chrome

Comment: Then you have not found the 'dat' object, and that is your problem. Where did 'dat' come from? Do a console.log(dat), and if that is undefined, you are not able to reference it.